# How do I increase PPPoE MTU?

Tags: pppoe

I have an Ubuntu Server 14.04 install which is connected to the internet using PPPoE. At the moment my `ppp0` interface have an MTU of 1492 which mostly works.

I'd like to increase the MTU to 1500, which is supported by my ISP.

So far I have increased the MTU of the underlying Ethernet interface to 1508, and I have tried adding the following lines in `/etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider`

```
mtu 1500
mru 1500
```

But my `ppp0` interface still has an MTU of 1492. I believe the syntax of my added lines is correct, since using values lower than 1492 does work as expected.

Manually changing the MTU of the `ppp0` interface to 1500 after it has been brought up works, but it only affects packets in one direction. Doing that I am able to send 1500 bytes packets across the internet and they will arrive at their destination with no fragmentation. But incoming traffic to me is still sent in 1492 byte fragments.

By capturing traffic on the Ethernet interface as the PPPoE connection is brought up, I can see that in the configuration request that my Ubuntu Server 14.04 machine sends to the provider, the MRU is specified as 1492. So I know the issue is on my end of the connection.

Why does Ubuntu Server 14.04 use 1492 as MRU in the configuration request, when the configuration file says 1500? And how can I change it to 1500?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the `ppp` source code by typing these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep ppp
apt-get source ppp
```

In the header file `pppd/plugins/rp-pppoe/pppoe.h` I found this:

```
/* Header size of a PPPoE packet */
#define PPPOE_OVERHEAD 6  /* type, code, session, length */
#define HDR_SIZE (sizeof(struct ethhdr) + PPPOE_OVERHEAD)
#define MAX_PPPOE_PAYLOAD (ETH_DATA_LEN - PPPOE_OVERHEAD)
#define MAX_PPPOE_MTU (MAX_PPPOE_PAYLOAD - 2)
```

`ETH_DATA_LEN` is defined in `/usr/include/linux/if_ether.h`

```
#define ETH_DATA_LEN      1500            /* Max. octets in payload        */
```

And in `pppd/plugins/rp-pppoe/plugin.c` I found this:

```
    if (lcp_allowoptions[0].mru > MAX_PPPOE_MTU)
        lcp_allowoptions[0].mru = MAX_PPPOE_MTU;
    if (lcp_wantoptions[0].mru > MAX_PPPOE_MTU)
        lcp_wantoptions[0].mru = MAX_PPPOE_MTU;
```

What all of this means is that the `rp-pppoe` plugin has a hard coded limit of 1492 bytes. And the only way to increase it is by modifying the source and rebuild the plugin with a higher limit.

By removing the above four lines from `plugin.c` and rebuilding the module, I was able to increase the MTU from 1492 to 1500. This only works as long as the underlying line is known to support the larger size, which happens to be the case on my connection.

In order to detect the capability of the underlying line it would be necessary to use a newer pppd version with RFC 4638 support. Ubuntu 16.04 has a newer pppd version and thus should be capable of using larger MTU sizes for PPPoE without needing to recompile any code.

Comment: @malo That is no longer true. Modern Ethernet equipment is often found with support for MTU sizes as large as 9000 bytes. And RFC 4638 allows for larger MTU sizes to be negotiated on PPPoE. Ubuntu 14.04 just doesn't appear to support RFC 4638 out of the box.

Comment: only gigabit does such massive MTU , most of the internet runs with an MTU of 576 so you really wont get more speed doing this , you will probably just give someone elses router more work to do.

Comment: >most of the internet runs with an MTU of 576... What? Maybe in India. Only dial-up used this value. I have a website with no specific target country and most users worldwide have between 1Mb and 4Mb ADSL. Which coincidentally also happens to have PPPoE under the hood imposing the same 1492B limit.

Answer (score -1):

you could run pppd via strace and filter to display 'open' requests to see which files its opening to get its config from.

```
sudo strace -f -e open pppd
```

In my experience (of uk broadband) all connections have been 1492 if they go over BT , is there a specific reason you need another 8 octets ?

My understanding is that if you don't match the MRU properly you can end up having your packets become multiple packets, especially if you don't allow things like an 8 octet overhead for encapsulation.

Comment: `1.` I have experienced a PMTU problem on a 6in4 tunnel, which would go away if my PMTU was 1500 bytes. `2.` It seems silly to be using a 1492 byte MTU when the entire path supports 1500 bytes, and it is just my Ubuntu box which for some reason suggests a lower value during negotation.

Comment: I have updated the question with a list of every configuration file read by `pon dsl-provider`, but I didn't find anything useful that way.

Comment: Turns out the limit was hard coded in the `rp-pppoe` plugin. So I have removed the list of configuration files from my question again as that wasn't relevant after all.